# Replace diacritic letters with equivalent

Tags: actionscript-3, replace, character, diacritics

I'm trying to replace:

`á, ă, â ...` with `a`
`í, ì, ĭ, î, ǐ, ï, ḯ ...` with `i`
`ú, ü ...` with `u`

And so on.

What I am doing now is this: `str.replace(/[íìĭîǐïḯ]/gi,'i'`.
Also, if I want to match all of them I need to call replace for each grouping.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you have to match each group. Take a look into this example, although it is javascript it's very complete script and easy to get it to work in actionscript:
http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics/

Comment: That is awesome, Dome. Thanks. But... should I not be worried about performance? Running so many RegExp replaces looks like a lot of processing.